# How do you end an Application from a Web Method within a Web Service?

Tags: c#, web-services, webmethod, termination

I'm trying to create a method within a web service that will terminate the application when called. The purpose of this is to end a game being played with a Windows form. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I can "stop" the web service by clearing the session variables. Is this true? Using code:

```
        Session.Contents.Abandon();
```

Comment: No, all that will do is flush any of the current user's credentials involved with connecting to the web service in question. It will not stop the service (others could be connected and have different session data) nor will it kill any processes you had attached.

Answer (score 1):

Generally your web method is in a completely different process, hence you cannot directly terminate the process [of the caller]. You should communicate the need to terminate back to the caller either via an indicator in the response or via an Exception (as part of a FaultContract).

Answer (score 0):

If the WinForm is running on the server, where the web service is, you can stop it using Process.Kill method
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx

Comment: Only if you're running as admin, which requires a lot of configuration. Dont do that!